# Pyenchant - Italian and Spanish Languages

Tags: python, pyenchant

I am using **pyenchant** package for spell check in Python. I am able to do it successfully for languages English, French, German.

Also, I want to do it for languages Italian and Spanish. I looked into available dictionaries in enchant using `enchant.list_languages()` and I got only `['de_DE', 'en_AU', 'en_GB', 'en_US', 'fr_FR']`.

I am looking for how to do spell check for Italian and Spanish using **enchant** package or **any other package/techniques.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any myspell, aspell, openoffice.org or ispell dictionary with Pyenchant. It will depend upon which operating system you have as how you get them installed.

For example on Ubuntu you can install any of these packages e.g.

```
    sudo apt-get install myspell-it myspell-es
```

For Ubuntu 14.04 the packages are listed here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/myspell-dictionary

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/aspell-dictionary

http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/openoffice.org-dictionaries

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ispell-dictionary

Windows users see http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html#windows-users

Once installed the dictionaries will show when you run:

```
enchant.list_languages()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hunspell` for `italian` it will replace it, and `myspell` for `spanish`

`sudo apt install hunspell-it` *Italian*

`sudo apt install myspell-es` *Spanish*